# how to make a vectorized file in python. I need to convert tweets to vector form inorder to run a code in bayesian network

Tags: python-2.7, vectorization, tweets, bayesian-networks

Is it possible to make a dataset atleast? I am doing sentiment analysis and is getting polarity of the message
I was following this tutorial. But it is not the data set required.
http://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/

It would be great if anyone could explain the csv file given here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the process of converting a collection of text documents into numerical feature vectors is called vectorization. There are several techniques or concepts that can be used to vectorize text documents(for eg. word embeddings, bag of words, etc.).

Bag of words is one of the simplest ways to vectorize text into numerical features. TfIdf is an effective vectorization technique based on the bag of words concept.

On a very basic level, TfIdf uses a set of unigrams or bigrams(n-grams in general) from the entire text corpus and uses them as the features for all your text documents(tweets in your case). So if you imagine your text corpus as a table of numerical values then each row would be a text document(a tweet in your case) and each column would be a unigram(which is basically a word) and the value of each cell (i,j) in the table would depend on the term frequency of unigram j in the tweet i(the number of times that the particular unigram occurs in the tweet) and the inverse of the document frequency of the unigram j(the number of tweets that the particular unigram occurs in all the tweets combined). Hence, you would have a list of tweets as vectors which would have a numerical tfidf values corresponding to each feature(unigram).

For more information on how to implement tfidf look at the following links:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#the-bag-of-words-representation

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html